# Save unbalanced dictionary in txt file

Tags: python, file, dictionary, encoding, utf-8

I need to export an unbalanced dictionary in a txt file. The dictionary contains UTF-8 characters which must be kept. The example is as follow:

```
dict = {"Polić":("a","c","e"), "Batman":("b","d")}
```

In the end, I would need the following text file:

```
"Polić","a","c","e"
"Batman","b","d"
```

I tried the following code

```
with open("my/File.txt", "w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for p in dict.items(): 
        file.writelines("%s:%s\n" % p)
```

But it does not work when the number of values is not the same for all the keys. Does anyone have an answer ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
my_dict = {"Polic":("a","c","e"), "Batman":("b","d")}

with open("my/File.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for k,v in my_dict.items(): 
        file.write('"{}","{}"\n'.format(k, '","'.join(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in my_dict.items()]
```